# How to use hash values for passwords in a derby database

Tags: md5, derby

I need the passwords going into my derby database to be hash values they are currently strings. How can I achieve this?

```
                String sql = "insert into MPP_USERS "
                + " (LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME,EMAIL_ADDRESS,PASSWORD)" + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

                    ps= con.prepareStatement(sql); 
                    ps.setString(1, lastname);
                    ps.setString(2, firstname);
                    ps.setString(3, email);
                    ps.setString(4,password);
                    System.out.println("Insert complete.");
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    System.out.println("Insert complete.");
```

Also how do you validate the hash value when the user logs in? here is my validate method.

```
        con = DataConnect.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement("Select EMAIL_ADDRESS,PASSWORD from MPP_USERS where EMAIL_ADDRESS = ? and PASSWORD = ? ");
        ps.setString(1, email);
        ps.setString(2, password);


        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()) {
            //result found, means valid inputs
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: For the 1000th time, you don't "encrypt" passwords in a database, you "hash" them. MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, it is a *hash* algorithm.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to have Derby do this? Or are you asking how to do this yourself, in your own Java code?

Comment: @BryanPendleton Yes a way where Derby can do it.

Comment: I think it will be easier to do it in your Java code. But first, read this: http://blog.codinghorror.com/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly/